# Trouble displaying data in React modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I am currently working on a project where I am building a single page app using React. The goal of the project is to have a map of an area that will be hosting a winery/wine vendor tour, and on the map have buttons the user can click/tap to display info about each vendor/vineyard.

I am currently stuck trying to get the modal to display the info of the specified vendor/vineyard button that the user clicks, i.e. the user clicks the button for Vendor 1, and the modal pops up and displays the relevant info for Vendor 1. The same for Vendor 2 and so on. Currently the modal is not displaying anything except for a button to close the modal. My question is how do I get the info for each vendor/vineyard to display for the corresponding button on click?

I've tried including .map method in the return in Vendor.js, but that displays all the vendor/vineyard info for every one in the modal.

My current file structure is:

```
App
  |_src
    |_components
      |_Button
        |_Popup
          |_Vendor
```

Vendor.js:

```
import React from './react';

const Vendor = () => {

    let vendors = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Vendor 1 Name',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Vendor 2 Name'
        }
    ]

    const [vendorsList, setVendorsList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setVendorsList([...vendors]);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='card' key={vendors.id}>
            <h3>{vendors.title}</h3>
            <h3>{vendors.hours}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default Vendor;
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
    return(
        <div className='App'>
            <Map />
            <Info />
        </div>
        <div className='app__button'>
            <Button />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Button.js:

```
const Button = () => {
    const [buttonPopup, setButtonPopup] = useState(false);

    return(
        <div className='popup'>
            <button onClick={() => setButtonPopup(true)}>Button</button>
            <Popup
                trigger={buttonPopup}
                setTrigger={setButtonPopup}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Popup.js:

```
const Popup = (props) => {
    return (props.trigger) ? (
        <div className='popup-inner'>
            <button className='close-button' onClick={() => props.setTrigger(false)}>X</button>
            {props.children}
            <Vendor />
        </div>
    ) : "";
};
```

If there is anything else that I can include to help, I'd be happy to. TIA!

Comment: I don't see anything that ties a button to a given vendor (or anything that iterates over the vendors, for that matter).

Comment: How would I tie the button to a given vendor? I've been having trouble with that.

Also, I removed the .map method that was in the return of Vendor.js. It was displaying vendor info, but for every vendor and not just one.

The return used to be:

`return(
    vendorsList.map((vendor) => (
        <div className='card' key={vendors.id}>

Comment: You'd probably render a component that displays each vendor. That component would take a vendor, and use the vendor ID as an argument to a click handler. You might want to take a quick step back and spin through a React tutorial that does "something with a list of somethings".

Comment: Thanks! also sorry for the mess of a reply, I was trying to get the snippet to behave, and it timed out on the edit. But I think thats enough to get me going in the right direction. 

And just for clarity, you suggest I create a new component that renders all vendors info, then using the vendor ID as an argument to a click handler, have that new component display only what was selected by ID?

Answer (score 0):

It look like you made a mistake in your Vendor.js file, you have an Array of vendors but you are displaying it like if it was a single object. You have to make a map over it like this :

end of Vendor.js:

```
    return (
        <>
          {vendors.map((vendor) => (
            <div className="card" key={vendor.id}>
              <h3>{vendor.title}</h3>
              <h3>{vendor.hours}</h3>
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
    )
```

But if you want to get one button by vendor and display on popup the info from that vendor, you should do :

Vendor.js:

```
import React from './react';

const Vendor = ({vendor}) => {

    return (
        <div className='card' key={vendor.id}>
            <h3>{vendor.title}</h3>
            <h3>{vendor.hours}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default Vendor;
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
    let vendors = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Vendor 1 Name',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Vendor 2 Name'
        }
    ]

    const [vendorsList, setVendorsList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setVendorsList([...vendors]);
    }, []);

    return(
        <div className='App'>
            <Map />
            <Info />
        </div>
        <div className='app__button'>
            {vendors.map((vendor) => (<Button vendor={ vendor } />)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Button.js:

```
const Button = ({vendor}) => {
    const [buttonPopup, setButtonPopup] = useState(false);

    return(
        <div className='popup'>
            <button onClick={() => setButtonPopup(true)}>Button</button>
            <Popup
                trigger={buttonPopup}
                setTrigger={setButtonPopup}
                vendor={ vendor }
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Popup.js:

```
const Popup = (props) => {
    return (props.trigger) ? (
        <div className='popup-inner'>
            <button className='close-button' onClick={() => props.setTrigger(false)}>X</button>
            {props.children}
            <Vendor vendor={ props.vendor }/>
        </div>
    ) : "";
};
```

Comment: I tried implementing your second solution (as thats more in line with what I'm looking to do) but when the button is clicked, the modal pops up and nothing is displayed still.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the {} around vendor, I edit the answer, you can try now

Comment: this line changed : const Vendor = ({vendor}) => {

Comment: Tell me if it's ok for you and dont forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So you have a list of vendors with ids associated, the best way to get the data into the modal would be to pass the vendor Id to the popup, then get the vendor from the list with the matching id from inside the popup.

You would do this by making the vendor list that is currently in the Vendor component live outside the component and be exported so but can use it everywhere. Then, the vendor component takes in an id and gets the vendor with that id by doing:

const vendor = Vendors.find(vendor => vendor.Id === Id);

Then you render
…
vendor.title
…
…
vendor.hours
…
In your Vendor component.

I hope this helps, I write it on my phone so please lmk if you have questions!

Answer (score 0):

The current problem is that in the Vendors component, the component's render method given an array of vendors and tries to get data from on that array, rather than on a single object. `<h3>{vendors.title}</h3>` is not going to return the title, because vendors is an array, not a single object with a property for `title`.

That is why nothing renders. However, the issue is that you can't just iterate on that list in the Vendor component, because right now that component does not know which vendor to display. A parent ought to pass in a vendor object into this child component. Here is an example!

If each Button opens a modal for a specific vendor, VendorList could live higher in the component structure to pass down the necessary information, like so:

```js
function App() {
    let vendors = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Vendor 1 Name',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Vendor 2 Name'
        }
    ]

    return(
        <div className='App'>
            <Map />
            <Info />
        </div>
        
        {/* create 1 button per vendor */}
        {vendors.map(vendor => (
          <div className='app__button'>
            <Button vendor={vendor} />
          </div>
        ))}
    );
}

// button now receives a single vendor on the props obj
const Button = (props) => {
    const [buttonPopup, setButtonPopup] = useState(false);

    return(
        <div className='popup'>
            <button onClick={() => setButtonPopup(true)}>Button</button>
            <Popup
                trigger={buttonPopup}
                setTrigger={setButtonPopup}
                vendor={props.vendor}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

// keep passing the vendor in the props...
const Popup = (props) => {
    return (props.trigger) ? (
        <div className='popup-inner'>
            <button className='close-button' onClick={() =>   
               props.setTrigger(false)}>X</button>
            {props.children}
            <Vendor vendor={props.vendor}/>
        </div>
    ) : "";
};

// until finally the Vendor component receives the individual vendor it should display
const Vendor = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='card' key={props.vendor.id}>
            <h3>{props.vendor.title}</h3>
            <h3>{props.vendor.hours}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This much prop passing isn't always ideal, but it's a good way to learn how to move data across React components! Hope this helps!

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much! I'll be re-reading this a few times to help the info sink in.